# Cache.getOrElse on Futures in Playframework

Tags: scala, caching, playframework-2.0

What is the correct way to cache the result of future in playframework. E.g.:

```
val userGravatar: Future[JsValue] = RemoteGravatarService.get(user.id, user.email)

object RemoveGravatarService {
  def get(userId: String, email: String): Future[JsValue] = {
    Cache.getOrElse("gravatar-for-$userId", 1.hour) {
      WS.url("gravatar.com/email=$email").get().asJson
    }
  }
}
```

We don't want to ask (this fictional) "Gravatar" every time, because it doesn't change *that* often. But we need som userGravatar info quite often locally.

Here we cache the future itself, but actually we only want to cache the result of the future. Is there a convenient/correct way to do this in play?

Comment: Any type, but let's say `JsValue` (since it's serializeable). Updated example with type annotations. The important thing here is that I want the cache to respond with `Future.successful(previousJsonResult)` if the value is ready in cache.

Comment: You could use spray cache

Answer (score 7):

There isn't a method in Play's API that will handle `Future`s. You can wrap Play's cache API to handle the `orElse` case where it returns a `Future`. Generically:

```
object FutureCache {

    def getOrElse[A](key: String, expiration: Int)(orElse: => Future[A])
      (implicit app: Application, ct: ClassTag[A], ec: ExecutionContext): Future[A] = {
        Cache.getAs[A](key).map(Future.successful).getOrElse {
            val value = orElse
            value onSuccess { case result => Cache.set(key, result, expiration) }
            value
        }
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
FutureCache.getOrElse[JsValue]("gravatar-for-$userId", 3600) {
  WS.url("gravatar.com/email=$email").get().map(_.json)
}
```

You could also create an overload for `getOrElse` that uses `Duration`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Promise[JsValue], something like that:

```
val userGravatar: Future[JsValue] = RemoteGravatarService.get(user.id, user.email)

object RemoveGravatarService {
  def get(userId: String, email: String): Future[JsValue] = {
    Cache.getOrElse("gravatar-for-$userId", 1.hour) {
      Promise[JsValue].completeWith(WS.url("gravatar.com/email=$email").get().map(_.json)
    }.future
  }
}
```